# Trouble with Twitter river plugin,while using with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to create a listening tool for a few keywords in twitter and for that I have successfully created my Twitter application and got the respective "Access keys tokens". 
The problem is that when I type in this command in the terminal,it returns error

```
`curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/listening_river/_meta' -d '{
"type" : "twitter",

"twitter" : {
"oauth" : {
"consumer_key" : "my consumer key",
"consumer_secret" : "my consumer secret",
"access_token" : "my access token",
"access_token_secret" : "my access token secret"
},
"filter" : {
"tracks" : "whitehouse,pentagon",
"language" : "en"
}
},
"index" : {
"index" : "listening_river",
"type" : "listening",
"bulk_size" : 100,
"flush_interval" : "5s"
}
}'`
```

I have checked the access keys and tokens. Everything seems to be fine. It returns the following error : "curl (7) couldn't connect to the host"
Im new to ES,so can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you there is no elasticsearch instance running on your machine,that is,you may have forgotten to start elasticsearch in your server.
Make sure that elasticsearch is up and running in your machine.
You can do that by typing in the following command in the terminal:

```
 "sudo service elasticsearch start".
```

Also after setting up the river you can check whether it is working or not,by using the following command :

```
 "tail -f /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log"
```

For more references,you can visit this [link](http://blog.qbox.io/using-kibana-and-elasticsearch-to-examine-twitter-trends),which explains the creation and setting up of twitter rivers,with examples.